# How to calculate the median in column excluding cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, cell, rows, median, indicator

I have got a column with data and I want to calculate the median excluding some values.

=median(B2:B40)

There is an indicator column in A2:A40: 1= value in column B has to be included in the calculation of the median and  0= value in column B has to be excluded.

If possible: no arrays formula

Thank you for your help.

Comment: so sumproduct() or even multiply by column A

Comment: thank you. How would you integrate the median formula I for example want the answer in just one cell, let's say in cell C2

Comment: Without any data, I would go with sumproduct() - as you have a binary value and multiplying by zero gives zero which excludes those values.